# WebMail.Send blocks for a long time - can the call be async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, razor, webmail

I'm using `WebMail.Send` in my Razor app where the contents of the mail is the data the user entered in a form. It takes several seconds to process, which is long for the user without any feedback.

Is there any easy way to do this async or in another thread so the user isn't blocked while that's happening? Unlike many of the examples with async/await, I don't need to be informed when it's done - I just don't want the user to wait with no feedback that anything is happening.

Comment: Have you tried something of the sort: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeFunction())`

Comment: Yes - I tried:  var t = Task.Run( () => WebMail.Send( 
                    to: "someguy@live.com",
                    subject: "some subject",
                    body: "some message",
                    isBodyHtml: true
                    ));   , and I get "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" as an error. If I replace the WebMail.Send() call with something like Console.Writeline() I get no errors, so there's something about the WebMail call that is not working.